# error : cannot read property 'setState' on fetch method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created method to handle a submit from a form to store data via API.I want to show snackbar after successfully store data.But this always show  error : cannot read property 'setState'.But the error message marked at the line fetch("http://localhost/lumen/udemy-react-api/public/api/departments" not at the line this.setState.Please help me to find the problem.I got stucked at this issue for 2 hours.

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch("http://localhost/lumen/udemy-react-api/public/api/departments", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        id: null,
        name: event.target.name.value
      })
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result =>
        this.setState({ snackbaropen: true, snackbarmsg: result.message })
      )
  }
```

Comment: In normal function, `this` doesn't refer to the class. So you need to bind `handleSubmit()` function. Otherwise i suggest you to use arrow function, which removes all the `this` related complexity/problems.

Comment: thanks for the explaination sir.It helps me to find the problem

Answer (score 4):

You have a calling context problem

Try binding the `handleSubmit()` method to `this` in constructor

```
  class MYclass {

    constructor(){
       this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       .....

  }
```

Comment: And perhaps `return fetch`.

Comment: @seanulus no need to `return fetch`. What @charlietfl is the classic solution

Comment: or just `handleSubmit = (event) => {` if the project setup supports class properties.

Comment: thank you guys,that was my mistake.I don't know if i have to bind the method to constructor.